# Pandas conditional formatting on multiple columns with different criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, pandas-styles

I would like conditionally format a df with multiple criterias according to its columns, which looks like below:

|  | business_entity | 2021-H1 | 2022-H1 | 2022-H2 | Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 4 | DEF | 99 | 99 | 100 | 1 |
| 8 | GHI | 97 | 97 | 98 | 1 |
| 20 | JKl | 98 | 98 | 98 | 0 |
| 3 | MNO | 98 | 97 | 98 | 1 |
| 23 | PQR | 0 | 0 | 98 | 98 |
| 19 | STU | 98 | 97 | 98 | 1 |
| 22 | VWX | 96 | 98 | 98 | 0 |
| 17 | DFD | 97 | 99 | 98 | -1 |

What I'm trying to do is to format the df with the following criteria:

for columns from 2021-H1 to 2022-H2:
if values >= 89 (green), if values >=79.5 and <89 (orange), and if value <79.5 (red)

for "Movement" column:
if  value >=.05 (green), value >-.05 and <.05 (orange), and value <=-.05 (red)

I've done some research here and come up with the below code:

```
division_summary_table.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['background:green'
          if (colname=='2021-H1' and value >=89)
          else 'background:orange'
          if (colname=='2021-H1' and value >=79.5)
          else 'background:red'
          if (colname=='2021-H1' and value <79.5)
          else 'background:green'
          if (colname=='2022-H1' and value >=89)
          else 'background:orange'
          if (colname=='2022-H1' and value >=79.5)
          else 'background:red'
          if (colname=='2022-H1' and value <79.5)
          else 'background:green'
          if (colname=='2022-H2' and value >=89)
          else 'background:orange'
          if (colname=='2022-H2' and value >=79.5)
          else 'background:red'
          if (colname=='2022-H2' and value <79.5)
          else 'background:green'
          if (colname=='Movement' and value >=.5)
          else 'background:orange'
          if (colname=='Movement' and value >=0)
          else 'background:red'
          if (colname=='Movement' and value <-.5)
          else ' '
          for colname, value in x.items()],axis=1).format(precision=0)
```

It works fine for now but really "verbose". Since I need to produce multiple table like this and to apply the same formatting, I tried to to write a simple function then reuse it later:

```
def styler(df):
    for colname, value in df.items():

        if (colname=='2021-H1' and value >=89):
            return 'background:green'
        elif (colname=='2021-H1' and value >=79.5):
            return 'background:orange'
        elif (colname=='2021-H1' and value <79.5):
            return 'background:red'
        else:
            return ''


division_summary_table.apply(styler)
```

When I apply it gives me the below error:

> "Function <function styler at 0x000002566633C940> resulted in the
> apply method collapsing to a Series".Usually, this is the result of
> the function returning a single value, instead of list-like.

I'm a beginner and really have no idea how to fix it. Appreciate your advise on a better way to accomplish what I want to achieve. One more thing I need help is how to save the tables in as png file with the conditional formattings.

Comment: Can you please tidy up the indentation of your code? It's basic courtesy to the helpers here to present your code neatly for readability. See also [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define functions to `colorize` subset of columns:

```
def colorize_year(v):
    return np.select(
        [v >= 89, (v < 89) & (v >= 79.5), v < 79.5],
        ['background: green', 'background: orange', 'background: red']
    )

def colorize_movement(v):
    return np.select(
        [v >= .05, (v < .05) & (v >= -.05), v <= -.05],
        ['background: green', 'background: orange', 'background: red']
    )

(
    df.style
    .apply(colorize_movement, subset=['Movement'])
    .apply(colorize_year, subset=['2021-H1', '2022-H1', '2022-H2'])
)
```

Result

[image]